# Check if variable value is same as string

Tags: php, if-statement

I would like to have if condition which can validate PHP variable has value like string

```
 $string = "language English"
 $lan = "ENG"
 //So $lan has value "ENG" which is in string 
 if($lan LIKE $string )
 {
         // DO some thing.
 }
```

Is there way to check this? or any other ways, good examples, good practice.?

Comment: You are looking for [`stristr`](http://php.net/stristr) or [`stripos`](http://php.net/stripos).

Comment: @mario Why do people like you comment rather than answer when you clearly know the answer? lol just wondering :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// If not case sensitive

if (strpos($string,$lan) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}

// If case sensitive

if (stripos($string,$lan) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: `stripos` otherwise no match.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

 $string = "language English";
 $lan = "ENG";

 $eng = '/'.$lan.'/i'; // 'i' indicates a case-insensitive search
 $check=preg_match($eng, $string);

 if($check)
 {
 echo "Match Found";    
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Match not found";
 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also use is_numeric function 

if (!is_numeric("test")) 
 {
 echo "Yes";
 } else {
 echo "No";
 }
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Comment: if(!is_numeric("ENG"))
{// // DO some thing.}

Comment: OP want to do something if the value `eng` appears in another string `language English`. Not when the value is a non-numeric